# button inside table row of data to delete data row

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to display rows of data in a table. and i wanted to put a button at the end of each table so that i would be able to delete/edit that specific row. so here it is

```
$found_row = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from TICKET INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON TICKET.CUSTOMER_ID=CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID");

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
echo "<tr>
        <th>Ticket ID</th>
        <th>Customer ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Pickup Date</th>
        <th>Pickup Time</th>
        <th>Delivery Date</th>
        <th>Delivery Time</th>
        <th>Payment Mode</th>
        <th>Payment Status</th>
        <th>Ticket Status</th>
        <th>EDIT STATUS</th>
        </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    $found_row = true;
    $wow = $row['TICKET_ID'];
    echo " <tr>
            <td>".$row['TICKET_ID']."</td> 
            <td>".$row['CUSTOMER_ID']."</td>
            <td>".$row['CUSTOMER_NAME']."</td>
            <td>".$row['CUSTOMER_ADDRESS']."</td>
            <td>".$row['CUSTOMER_PHONE']."</td>
            <td>".$row['CUSTOMER_EMAIL']."</td>
            <td>".$row['TICKET_PICKUP']."</td>
            <td>".$row['TICKET_PTIME']."</td>
            <td>".$row['TICKET_DELIVERY']."</td>
            <td>".$row['TICKET_DTIME']."</td>
            <td>".$row['TICKET_PAYMENT']."</td>
            <td>".$row['PAYMENT_STATUS']."</td>
            <td>".$row['TICKET_STATUS']."</td>
            <td>".("<a href='cancelticket1.php?id=$wow'>Delete</a>")."</td></tr>";

    }
    if ($found_row == false) {
            echo "No Ticket Submitted";
        }

    echo "</table>";
```

so for now i am able to redirect the page with return value of the ticket_id for each row.. the url being /cancelticket1.php?id=1001 for example. and in the page cancelticket1.php, here are the code:

```
$cancelticket=$_GET['$wow'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM TICKET WHERE TICKET_ID=$cancelticket";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Ticket Has Been Deleted";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

from here I am stumped on how to retrieve that ticket_id, and i keep getting error message however i tried. please help me.

Comment: instead of `<td>".("<a href='cancelticket1.php?id=$wow'>Delete</a>")."</td></tr>";`

change the $wow to $row:

`<td>".("<a href='cancelticket1.php?id=**$row'**>Delete</a>")."</td></tr>";`

Comment: @lothux1987 `$row` is an __array__.

Comment: `$cancelticket=$_GET['wow'];`, without `$`. Also it would be helpfull to show your error message.

Comment: And you pass value in `id` variable, so it is even `$cancelticket=$_GET['id'];`

Comment: @u_mulder i did like what u wrote, but i'm still getting the same error message on the cancelticket1.php page. : Notice: Undefined index: wow in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\cancelticket1.php on line 31
Error: DELETE FROM TICKET WHERE TICKET_ID=
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Btw, if `id` will be `= 0 OR 1 = 1` all your tickets will be deleted)

Comment: @u_mulder yup u are right.. its working now. thnks!

Comment: Don't use evil SELECT *. Instead name and qualify each of the columns you want returned

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change Your Code:

```
$cancelticket=$_GET['$wow'];
```

to

```
$cancelticket=$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: wow that works.. thanks dude!